# If condition for Yaml file- Java

Tags: java, yaml

I have the Yaml file:

```
#Define CDN domains
---
CDN: 
 quality: 200..300
 cost: low
 Video-type: mp4
```

and with this Java code, I retrieve sub values of CDN:

```
 // The path of your YAML file.

 Yaml yaml = new Yaml();

 Map<String, Map<String, String>> values =
  (Map<String, Map<String, String>>) yaml
    .load(new FileInputStream(new File("/workspace/servlet-yaml/src/test.yaml")));

for (String key : values.keySet()) {
  Map<String, String> subValues = values.get(key);
  for (String subValueKey : subValues.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(values); 
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
{CDN={quality=200..300, cost=low, Video-type=mp4}}
{CDN={quality=200..300, cost=low, Video-type=mp4}}
{CDN={quality=200..300, cost=low, Video-type=mp4}}
```

- First of all, I don't know why it repeats three times?
- Secondly, I want to write a code that 
  `if cost = low` , then do somthing.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, I dont know whay it reapets three times?

Because you tell it to. *For each subValueKey, print the whole value set*. There are three sub-keys, so the complete value set gets printed three times.

> Secondly, I want to write a code that if cost = low , then do somthing.

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();

Map<String, Map<String, String>> values =
        (Map<String, Map<String, String>>) yaml.load(
        new FileInputStream(new File(
        "/workspace/servlet-yaml/src/test.yaml")));

final Map<String, String> cdn = values.get("CDN");
    // or iterate over all keys like you currently do
final String cost = cdn.get("cost");
    // or iterate over all subkeys and compare them to "cost".
    // that way, it's easier to handle missing keys.
if ("low".equals(cost)) {
    // do something
}
```